# VSTS Cordova iOS build on MacinCloud agent failed - "Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined"

Tags: ios, cordova, azure-devops

I have VSTS build, that suppose to build iOS apps.
It runs on MacinCloud build agent, and uses "Cordova Build" step.
It wokred, but for some reason I started to receive some very informational exception -  "Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined"

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined
at /Users/vso113516/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.0.0/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:168:17
at _fulfilled (/Users/vso113516/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.0.0/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/vso113516/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.0.0/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/vso113516/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.0.0/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
at /Users/vso113516/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.0.0/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
at flush (/Users/vso113516/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.0.0/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Does anyone have any idea what should I look on to solve the problem?
Please, if you need more information, I'll provide it via question updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to downgrade to cordova version 7.1.0 (windows & ios). In the Cordova Build step, modify the 'Cordova Version' setting.

```
npm install -g cordova@7.1.0
```

and

```
$sudo npm install -g cordova@7.1.0
```

I've faced this same issue after upgraded to version 8.0.0 (even with the "Blank App" project).

Comment: It could be a good option to try, but since I'm using build agent and not mac machine, I don't have control on it's configuration.

Comment: Actually it worked. I forgot about "Cordova Version" option at "Cordova Build". I set it 7.1.0 and build succeeded. Thanks.

Comment: Confirm: 8.0.0 is bugged, downgrading to 7.1.0 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue I resolved it by creating taco.json in the project root, specifying "cordova-cli" version like below:

```
{
    "cordova-cli": "8.0.0"
}
```

As specified in https://github.com/Microsoft/taco-team-build#configureconfig, I was building it for android BTW. However, it seems this might help you as well.